# org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: java, aspectj

I have an AspectJ @Around annotation called @Profiled on 3 different methods in my code.
Each method (myMethod1 to myMethod3) calls a different constructor for the same class MyClass.

let's say:

```
 @Profiled
 public void myMethod1() {
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass(int,Date,List<int>);
 }

 @Profiled
 public void myMethod2() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(int,Date);
 }

 @Profiled
 public void myMethod3() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(int);
 }
```

When I call those methods, I get the following errors:

for myMethod2:

```
  org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

for myMethod3:

```
  org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

Any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: where is MyClass codE?

Comment: Can you show the actual arguments being passed to the constructors?

Comment: I am pretty limited as to what code I can share. I'll try to reproduce the error with a basic class and will post that if I can. I use the @Getter annotation from http://projectlombok.org/ for MyClass.

Comment: Lombock and AspectJ together could get messy.  No way to answer without some code.  Also, include the aspect.